# Custom view with touch event not working

Tags: android

I tried to make a simple custom view with TouchEvent. But if I click n drag the mouse cursor nothing is being drawn. Is this the way I should test TouchEvent on emulator ? Or I should run the app in real device (where it is also not working). Thanx

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
      private Path path = new Path();

      public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
      }


      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // nothing to do 
            break;
          default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: Try throwing `Log.d("DEBUG","Action Down");`, `Log.d("DEBUG","Action Move");`, and `Log.d("DEBUG","Action Up");` into your case statements so you can be sure your touch event is being captured...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html mentions 'Extend onDraw() and onMeasure()'. Does onMeasure() works fine for Your view? (guess no)

Comment: Yes, I did, events are being captured well.

Comment: are you sure you receive the events ? are you sure your path is updated? is there anything drawn at all? what happens if you initialize the path with preexisting elements ?

Comment: Yes, it draws well with a simple text.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in my emulator and it works, remember to keep the left button down while you move the mouse on the emulator view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : {
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        }

    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint);
}

private void init() {
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
}
```